# How to draw multiple graph in a layout using two y axises and one x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want show result of graph for time, y_min, y_max using one layout, draw two lines(min_value and max value) in y axis by time(X axis) and draw seperating graph of min_value and max_value in y axis.

##Data Set(test.csv)
X axis is time
Y axis is y_min, y_max

| time | min_value | max_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 945 | 0.892021996 | 0.964050503 |
| 955 | 0.769454489 | 0.884603426 |
| 965 | 0.774495876 | 0.884901433 |
| 975 | 0.745542623 | 0.897309432 |
| 985 | 0.753567721 | 0.912993446 |

```
  '''code'''
  Plot_graph = ggplot(.,aes(x=time, y=...))+geom_line(aes(group=Value, color=Value))+ geom_smooth(method="auto",aes(group=Value,color=Value))+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"))+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:8000*1000,limits=c(time_min,time_max)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:8000*0.1,limits=c(min_value,max_value)) + theme_classic()+labs(subtitle = "B. Original data (mean, min, max values)")
```

This code has some problem.

Let me know how to draw multiple graph in a layout using two y axises and one x axis.

Comment: Do you need a secondary y axis, or are you just looking to draw two lines from that data, with one line having y values associated from "min_value" and the other line having y values associated from "max_value"?  Looks like the two would share the same scale, right?

Comment: @chemdork123- I want to draw two lines(min_value and max value) in y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways you can do it - one is simple, the other is tidier.

The simple way would be to have two `geom_line` calls and change `aes(y= )` for each one (setting colour manually):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- dplyr::tribble(~time, ~min_value,   ~max_value,
                      945,  0.892021996,    0.964050503,
                      955,  0.769454489,    0.884603426,
                      965,  0.774495876,    0.884901433,
                      975,  0.745542623,    0.897309432,
                      985,  0.753567721,    0.912993446)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = min_value), colour = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = max_value), colour = "blue")
```

[image]

A tidy way would be to pivot your table to have the measurement name as a variable:

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(-time) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One possibility of a base solution would be, to draw first the line of let's say `min_value` and add the second `max_value` by using `lines()`

So this would look like:

```
plot(test.csv$time, test.csv$min_value, type = "l") 
lines(test.csv$time, test.csv$max_value)
```

For the `ggplot` version you need to convert your dataframe into long format:

```
test.csv <- melt(test.csv, id.vars = "time")
ggplot(test.csv, mapping = aes(x = variable, y = value, col = time)) +
geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you. but the graph that you made can't distibute min_value and max_value. I want to draw seperating graph of min_value and max_value in y axis.

Comment: to distinguish both lines you can give them different colors (see my example of ggplot), in the base version just add col = "red"

Comment: Are you looking to draw two graphs and have the min_value and the max_value on separate graphs?

Comment: I already finished drawing two lines in y axis based on code that you guys made. Now, I have no problem.